# ¿ Cómo se llaman estas escenas en Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Lo que me gustaría saber es cómo se llaman las escenas que usa el juego **"STACK"** que empieza con el nombre y de repente empieza a salir poco a poco el bloque y el botón play sin desaparecer el nombre, no es solo un simple cambio de escena.

Comment: Podrias agregar una captura de pantalla, no estoy seguro de a que te refieres

Comment: Es un video, no imagen... si no descargate "STACK" y es lo que quiero. Tener un texto , esperar unos segundos y que justo debajo del texto aparezca ya el boton play para jugar, y tambien se ve el escenario del juego.

Comment: Que no es 1a escena: texto y cargo segunda escena . Hace como una transicion y se carga poco a poco... a lo mejor lo hace asi con una animacion que se cargue poco a poco... pero no lo sé seguro, necesito saber como se llama para buscar informacion al respecto.